# Re-render component on props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, lifecycle

I guess this is a simple question but here goes: Is there a way of instructing your component to re-render when the props change? I have my component connected to the redux store which on a certain action updates the state, which then filters down into the props, upon which point I want the app to respond to the changes.

I guess you would use `componentDidUpdate()`?

Something like:

```
// ...
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (prevProps !== this.props) {
      // re-render x <-- not sure how to do this
   }
}
```

Plus what would be the method to re-render the **whole** component, and what would be the method of re-rendering **only the updated props**?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your questions with more information about the props? Your component should be rendering again "automatically" when changing your props (without needing to call that manually). Take a look at https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/585#issuecomment-133028621 to see if it helps

Answer (score 3):

You can call `this.forceUpdate()` in the method. Another way is `this.setState(this.state)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
componentWillReceiveProps (props){
 this.doSomething(props) // To some function.
 this.setState({data: props}) // This will update your component.
}
```

If your props is something that needs to change the state you will get an infinity loop.

Check out Reacts life cycle [here](http://codepen.io/eduardoboucas/pen/jqWbdb?js-preprocessor=none) by the way, might help aswell.

Comment: `componentWillReciveProps`  -> `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Can't make the edit as edits need a minimum of chars to change!